# Cayley-Bacharach property of points is linearly general position

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $P$ be a zero dimensional subscheme of length $m$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ which is in linearly general position. Further assume that there is a degree $d$ form passing through $P$. Can $P$ satisfy Cayley-Bacharach property for $\mathcal{O}(d)$

I got the answer of the question. In fact it can satisfy Cayley-Bacharach. For example if we choose 8 points in rational cubic curve in linearly general position then it always satisfies C-B for $\mathcal{O}(2)$.

Comment: why if $P$ is contained a unique curve of degree $d$, then it satisfies Cayley-Bacharach property for $\mathcal{O}(d)$ ?  Is it possible to give some lower bound on number of independent conditions imposed by $m$ points in linearly general position on sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ ?

Comment: We say $P$ satisfy CB for $\mathcal{O}(d)$ if any section of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ which vanishes at a co-length $1$ subscheme then it vanishes on $P$.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I had something different in mind. I delete my previous comments.

Comment: In any case can we give a a lower bound on the number of independent conditions imposed on sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ by $m$ points in general position ?

Comment: If $m\leq \frac{1}{2} (d+1)(d+2)=\dim H^0(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(d))$, $m$ general points impose $m$ independent conditions.

Comment: $m$ points in linearly general position need not be general points. There is a lower bound that $m$ points in linearly general position imposes at least $\text{min}\{3d +1, m\}$ conditions. Can we say something more  in some special cases? For example suppose we are given $14$ points in linearly general position not contained in rational normal curve, Can there be a quadric hypersurface passing through these $m$ points ?